# Fitting regression model causes "ValueError: 'Column name' is not in list" in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression, supervised-learning

I'm trying to fit some linear regression models using a DataFrame of nba players data to predict the target variable 'ORPM'. But when the following code runs:

```
X = orpm_data.drop(['Player','Lg','ORPM'],axis=1)
y = orpm_data['ORPM']
linreg = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('linreg', LinearRegression())])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=99)
linreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

the error:

> ValueError: 'ORPM' is not in list

is raised. What am I missing?

**EDIT** in response to comments:

print(X) prints the whole huge dataframe, which i can't represent - but X.info() returns this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 603 entries, 0 to 602
Data columns (total 29 columns):
Tm        603 non-null object
Season    603 non-null object
Age       603 non-null int64
G         603 non-null int64
GS        603 non-null int64
MP        603 non-null int64
FG        603 non-null float64
FGA       603 non-null float64
2P        603 non-null float64
2PA       603 non-null float64
3P        603 non-null float64
3PA       603 non-null float64
FT        603 non-null float64
FTA       603 non-null float64
ORB       603 non-null float64
DRB       603 non-null float64
TRB       603 non-null float64
AST       603 non-null float64
STL       603 non-null float64
BLK       603 non-null float64
TOV       603 non-null float64
PF        603 non-null float64
PTS       603 non-null float64
FG%       600 non-null float64
2P%       600 non-null float64
3P%       517 non-null float64
eFG%      600 non-null float64
FT%       588 non-null float64
TS%       600 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(23), int64(4), object(2)
memory usage: 136.7+ KB
```

print(y) returns:

```
None
0      2.38
1      3.87
2     -1.21
3      1.58
4     -4.30
5     -0.62
       ... 
598   -2.64
599    0.95
600   -2.98
601   -0.98
602   -2.08
Name: ORPM, Length: 603, dtype: float64
```

**EDIT2**: more details on the preprocessing pipeline

```
numeric_features = ['Age', 'G', 'GS', 'MP', 'FG', 'FGA',
       '2P', '2PA', '3P', '3PA', 'FT', 'FTA', 'ORB', 'DRB', 'TRB', 'AST',
       'STL', 'BLK', 'TOV', 'PF', 'PTS', 'FG%', '2P%', '3P%', 'eFG%', 'FT%',
       'TS%','ORPM']
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('PCA', PCA())])

categorical_features = ['Tm', 'Season']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])
```

Full stacktrace of error here: https://github.com/aj-1000/debugging-regression-model/blob/master/README.md

---

## Solved

Problem solved by removing 'ORPM' from numeric_features - because I was dropping that column before passing the data into the pipeline.

Comment: Print the X and the y pls

Comment: @MiguelSantos edited post to include y. Included X.info() instead of X due to size.

Comment: What line in the code is causing the error?

Comment: @aj1000 have u tried fitting the model without the train-test split? just to see if thats the issue?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov which two lines? The two defining X and y?

Comment: @vealkind the line "linreg.fit(X_train,y_train)"

Comment: @MiguelSantos - Thank you, I tried that just now but it produces the same error.

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace?  I'm wondering if there is something in your `preprocessor` step of the pipeline that could be causing the error that you haven't included in your question.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov - Thank you for your suggestion, I reloaded the dataframes, changed the order, ran it, but it still produced the same error

Comment: @aj1000 Try running your code line by line and tell us which line produces the error

Comment: Looking at your `preprocessor` try removing `ORPM` from `numeric_features`.  You're trying to scale your data with `StandardScaler()` using a column `ORPM` that does not exist in the data.

Comment: @vealkind I've added more details about the preprocessor to the post and uploaded the stacktrace here: https://github.com/aj-1000/debugging-regression-model/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @vealkind - Thank you so much! That seems to have solved it. Appreciate all of the help.